# How to define outline color from polygon layer using Python?

Tags: pyqgis

I´m using a QGIS 2.8.3 and I want to define a style for the legend of my polygon layer. I was using this code that works perfect:

```
str1= 'C:/Documents/Layer.shp'
myVectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer(str1, 'Layer', 'ogr')
myTargetField = 'FWI_AROME'
myRangeList = []
myOpacity = 1

# Make our first symbol and range...
myMin = 0.0
myMax = 8.5
myLabel = 'FWI Baixo'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#289e26')
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol1.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol1.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange1 = QgsRendererRangeV2(myMin, myMax, mySymbol1, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange1)

#now make another symbol and range...
myMin = 8.6
myMax = 17.2
myLabel = 'FWI Moderado'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#fee916')
mySymbol2 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol2.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol2.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange2 = QgsRendererRangeV2( myMin, myMax, mySymbol2, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange2)

#now make another symbol and range...
myMin = 17.3
myMax = 24.6
myLabel = 'FWI Elevado'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#ec6e00')
mySymbol3 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol3.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol3.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange3 = QgsRendererRangeV2( myMin, myMax, mySymbol3, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange3)

#now make another symbol and range..
myMin = 24.7
myMax = 38.3
myLabel = 'FWI Muito Elevado'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#cc292a')
mySymbol4 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol4.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol4.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange4 = QgsRendererRangeV2( myMin, myMax, mySymbol4, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange4)

#now make another symbol and range...
myMin = 38.4
myMax = 100.0
myLabel = 'FWI Extremo'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#75263b')
mySymbol5 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol5.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol5.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange5 = QgsRendererRangeV2( myMin, myMax, mySymbol5, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange5)

myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(myTargetField)
myVectorLayer.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(myVectorLayer)
```

The problem is that I want to define the outline color (that appears in black) to the same fill color.

How can I do this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try out the method 'createSimple' of your default symbol (it will be for a polygon layer) instead 'setColor'. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You could try to add QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2 to your symbols</strike>.
It is possible to modify the symbol by changing the existing symbolLayer (see http://qgis.org/api/classQgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2.html).  For example for the last symbol:

```
...
#now make another symbol and range...
myMin = 38.4
myMax = 100.0
myLabel = 'FWI Extremo'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#75263b')
mySymbol5 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol5.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol5.setAlpha(myOpacity)
mySymbol5.symbolLayer(0).setOutlineColor(myColour)
#outline_layer = QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2()
#outline_layer.setColor(myColour)
#outline_layer.setWidth(1.0)
#mySymbol5.appendSymbolLayer(outline_layer)
myRange5 = QgsRendererRangeV2( myMin, myMax, mySymbol5, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange5)
...
```

Comment: I used your code but I changed "myColor" into "myColour" and than it works. But in fact the outline is still black, I don't know why.

Comment: I want to change the black outline colour to the same fill colour of each class. If fill colour is green I want outline appears in green to, if fill colour is yellow I want outline appears in yellow to, as defined with hex value. How can I do this using python?

Comment: You could try to set the outlinewidth and see if that helps: outline_layer.setWidth(1.0)

Comment: Now it's working as I want. Many thanks, Håvard Tveite

Answer (score 2):

Try out the method 'createSimple' of your default symbol (it will be for a polygon layer) instead 'setColor'.

I tested my approach with this code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

myVectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()

myRenderer  = myVectorLayer.rendererV2()

if myVectorLayer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon:

    mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'#289e26', 
                                              'color_border':'#289e26',
                                              'width_border':'2'})

myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)

myVectorLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

and the shapefile of next image:

[image]

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS I got:

[image]

It works.

Comment: How to do that with pyqgis 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

By modifying some parts in the xunilk's answer, the following code works for me:

```
myVectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()
myRenderer  = myVectorLayer.renderer()
mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color':'#289e26', 
                                          'color_border':'#289e26',
                                          'width_border':'2'})
myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
myVectorLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Modificatons:

- rendererV2() -> renderer()
- QGis.Polygon -> QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry
- QgsFillSymbolV2 -> QgsFillSymbol